# Mongoose , response is not correct after remove

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nodes

How can I get a full data except deleted, after delete?

```
   Project.findOneAndRemove({_id:  projectID, name: projectName},   
        function(err, project){
            if (err) { 
                return res.json({message: 'Error on the server!', status: 500 });
            }
            // Here I need a full data except deleted one      
             console.log(project)      
            return res.json({project, status:200}); 
        }
    )
```

or Do I **find** again inside success callback to get full data?

```
Project.find({}, function(err, projects){
        if (err) return res.json({message: 'Error on the server!', status: 500 });
        return res.json(projects); 
    });
```

Comment: Yes, you have to do another request, as you did in the no error part, because findOneAndDelete function doesn't return anything as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you.

```
router.post('/deleteAndReturn', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Project.findOneAndRemove({ _id: projectId })

    const projects = await Project.find({})
    return res.status(200).json(projects)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send("Server Error")
  }
})
```